# Error inflating ListFragment from XML file

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am building an Android app using Fragments. In the XML file for one of my Fragments I simply have one `ListFragment` and one `Button`, like this (the `FilteredRecipesListFragment` is extending `ListFragment`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.mycompany.myapp.gui.FilteredRecipesListFragment
        android:id="@+id/filtered_recipes_list_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show_recipe_filter_dialog_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/show_recipe_filter_dialog_button"
        android:onClick="showFilter"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Fairly simple stuff. Furthermore the class `FilteredRecipesFragment` that is to inflate this XML file looks like this:

```
public class FilteredRecipesFragment extends Fragment {

    private FilteredRecipesListFragment mFilteredRecipesListFragment;
    private Button mShowRecipeFilterButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filtered_recipes_fragment, container, false);

        mFilteredRecipesListFragment = (FilteredRecipesListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.filtered_recipes_list_fragment);
        mShowRecipeFilterButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.show_recipe_filter_dialog_button);
        showRecipeFilterButton.setOnClickListener(new RecipeFilterButtonListener());

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Should also be straightforward. The problem is at the line inflating `FilteredRecipesListFragment`. Here I get `NoSuchMethodException: FilteredRecipesListFragment(Context, AttributeSet)`, because I have not implemented that constructor in my `FilteredRecipesListFragment` class. I am not sure why I would need that, since calling `super(Context, AttributeSet)` is not an option in `Fragments` as in `Views`.

And this is probably where I am heading wrong; am I approaching the whole concept of `Fragments` wrong in this case? Is it better practice or does it make more sense to use a `ListView` instead of a custom `ListFragment` inside another `Fragment`? If this is ok using the `FilteredRecipesListFragment(Context, AttributeSet)` method, how should I use this to make the class inflatable?

Here is my `FilteredRecipesListFragment` for reference:

```
public class FilteredRecipesListFragment extends ListFragment
{
    private FilteredRecipesListAdapter mRecipeAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        mRecipeAdapter = new FilteredRecipesListAdapter(getActivity(), null);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html).

Look at how you should declare a fragment in XML:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
          android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: I don't get it. Should *all* `Fragments` be specified like this in the *Activity* XML file? In my case, the provided XML file is the layout for a custom `Fragment` which further contains a custom `ListFragment`. What is wrong by specifying it like this? In the `onCreateView()` method of my custom `Fragment` I inflate the XML file which contains my custom `ListFragment`. Where should I put `<fragment android:name"..."` in this case?

Comment: @Krøllebølle In this case, you would replace `<com.mycompany.myapp.gui.FilteredRecipesListFragment` and the following text in the xml file you've posted here, with the format I noted above, but with `android:name` altered to match the location of your own fragment

Comment: I still get the `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: SelectedRecipesListFragment(Context,AttributeSet)`. I also changed the class name to "foo" just to verify that it didn't find the class then, and it didn't. It doesn't make sense to implement `SelectedRecipesListFragment(Context,AttributeSet)` for Fragments, right?

Comment: No, sorry, the error I copied in there is for another class. The class has a similar name, so I didn't see that it was another error. Seems like the `<fragment android:name="..."` does the trick. A final question here; since I put one `Fragment` (`ListFragment`) as a child of another `Fragment`, should I use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`? It seesm like both work, but what is most correct?